# command line mysql database administration tool

Tags: mysql, administration

Is there a command line script/tool I can use to administer a mysql database. I am in a tightly controlled environment and I can not use tools like phpmyadmin and can only access my database through command line (ssh connection). I can even live with something that can get show table status and describe all tables and write that into a text file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mysql` command-line tool [comes with the MySQL DBMS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you install the mysql client, the tool is called mysql.

$ mysql -u root -p

Here's some commands to get you started:

> use db_name; // db_name is your db
>
> help show;
>
> show tables;
>
> show columns from tbl_name; // tbl_name is a table in your db

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "USE database_name; DESCRIBE table_name;" | mysql -u user -p > outfile.txt
```

You can also enter the password just after the p flag without space, but remember to clear later your command history

Answer (score 1):

all you need to administrate mysql is mysql. start mysql on the command line and type the requests you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the mysql client (UNIX command `mysql`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. with your help uin the end, the solution that worked for me is to create a .sql files with all the command I needed to get my reports and maintenance. I then used $>tee out.txt; command to log my output to a file and it is working great now. To cancel tee use at mysql command line $>notee;